# Is recursion good in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have a table in SQL server that has the normal tree structure of Item_ID, Item_ParentID.
Suppose I want to iterate and get all CHILDREN of a particular Item_ID (at any level).

Recursion seems an intuitive candidate for this problem and I can write an SQL Server function to do this.

Will this affect performance if my table has many many records? 
How do I avoid recursion and simply query the table? Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new MS SQL 2005 you could use the `WITH`keyword

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91360/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-a-tree-using-sql) and particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91360/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-values-in-a-tree-using-sql#93202).

With Oracle you could use `CONNECT BY` keyword to generate hierarchical queries ([syntax](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)).

AFAIK with MySQL you'll have to use the recursion.

Alternatively you could always build a cache table for your records parent->child relationships

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer, it is possible to do some pretty sophisticated stuff in SQL Server  that normally needs recursion, simply by using an iterative algorithm. I managed to do an XHTML parser in Transact SQL that worked surprisingly well. The the code prettifier I wrote was done in a stored procedure. It aint elegant, it is rather like watching buffalo doing Ballet. but it works .

Comment: I once wrote a video player in Transact-SQL! :-P

Comment: You can, but it sure would be much easier to write an XHTML parser in Python/Ruby/C#/Java/Perl/LISP/etc.  And the performance would probably be way better....

Comment: No honest. It's here!
http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/getting-html-data-workbench/

Comment: I wrote lexical analyzer for T-SQL in T-SQL (SQL2K), for generating database documentation. It would pull definitions from syscomments, identify all the tokens, and then produce interlinked HTML files for each object. Click on a table name in a stored procedure, and it would take you to the table definition. Lots of fun! The hardest part was working around the 8000 character limit, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SQL 2005?

If so you can use Common Table Expressions for this.  Something along these lines:

```
;
with CTE (Some, Columns, ItemId, ParentId) as 
(
    select Some, Columns, ItemId, ParentId
    from myTable 
    where ItemId = @itemID
    union all
    select a.Some, a.Columns, a.ItemId, a.ParentId
    from myTable as a
    inner join CTE as b on a.ParentId = b.ItemId
    where a.ItemId <> b.ItemId
)
select * from CTE
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you will face with recursion and performance is how many times it will have to recurse to return the results.  Each recursive call is another separate call that will have to be joined into the total results.

In SQL 2k5 you can use a common table expression to handle this recursion:

```
WITH Managers AS 
( 
--initialization 
SELECT EmployeeID, LastName, ReportsTo  
FROM Employees 
WHERE ReportsTo IS NULL 
UNION ALL 
--recursive execution 
SELECT e.employeeID,e.LastName, e.ReportsTo 
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN Managers m  
ON e.ReportsTo = m.employeeID 
) 
SELECT * FROM Managers
```

or another solution is to flatten the hierarchy into a another table

**Employee_Managers**
ManagerId (PK, FK to Employee table)
EmployeeId (PK, FK to Employee table)

All the parent child relation ships would be stored in this table, so if Manager 1 manages Manager 2 manages employee 3, the table would look like:

```
ManagerId EmployeeId
1         2
1         3
2         1
```

This allows the hierarchy to be easily queried:

```
select * from employee_managers em 
inner join employee e on e.employeeid = em.employeeid and em.managerid = 42
```

Which would return all employees that have manager 42.  The upside will be greater performance, but downside is going to be maintaining the hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Joe Celko has a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558609202) (<- link to Amazon) specifically on tree structures in SQL databases. While you would need recursion for your model and there would definitely be a potential for performance issues there, there are alternative ways to model a tree structure depending on what your specific problem involves which could avoid recursion and give better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some more detail is in order.

If you have a master-detail relationship as you describe, then won't a simple JOIN get what you need?

As in:

```
SELECT
  SOME_FIELDS
FROM
  MASTER_TABLE MT
 ,CHILD_TABLE CT
WHERE CT.PARENT_ID = MT.ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need recursion for *children* - you're only looking at the level directly below (i.e. `select * from T where ParentId = @parent`) - you only need recursion for all *descendants*.

In SQL2005 you can get the descendants with:

```
with AllDescendants (ItemId, ItemText) as (
    select t.ItemId, t.ItemText 
        from [TableName] t
    where t.ItemId = @ancestorId
    union
    select sub.ItemId, sub.ItemText 
        from [TableName] sub
            inner join [TableName] tree
            on tree.ItemId = sub.ParentItemId
)
```

Comment: I think his problem is he wants "At a particular level".  Unless you store level number, how do you know what is at a particular level without going root = level 1, children of root = level 2, children of children = level 3, etc...

Not that recursion is needed...But there may be multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursion at all....
Note, I changed columns to ItemID and ItemParentID for ease of typing...

```
DECLARE @intLevel INT
SET @intLevel = 1
```

INSERT INTO TempTable(ItemID, ItemParentID, Level)
SELECT ItemID, ItemParentID, @intLevel
WHERE ItemParentID IS NULL

WHILE @intLevel < @TargetLevel
BEGIN
     SET @intLevel = @intLevel + 1
     INSERT INTO TempTable(ItemID, ItemParentID, Level)
          SELECt ItemID, ItemParentID, @intLevel
          WHERE ItemParentID IN (SELECT ItemID FROM TempTable WHERE Level = @intLevel-1)
     -- If no rows are inserted then there are no children
     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
       BREAK
END

SELECt ItemID FROM TempTable WHERE Level = @TargetLevel