# MySQL - Is it possible to get all sub-items in a hierarchy?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have looked at this:

[Select products where the category belongs to any category in the hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197362/select-products-where-the-category-belongs-to-any-category-in-the-hierarchy)

And it is talking about CTE, which doesn't exist in MySQL. I have structure like:

```
category_id | parent_category_id | name
```

I want to retrieve all the sub-categories ids of a given category_id. Is this possible without grabbing a tier, then looping through those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just simpy a *Adjacency Model* table? Then it is not possible in one query without knowing the maximum depth.

Food for thought  is [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (although I don't advocate using the *Nested Set Model* for data that alter regularly).

With a lot of (left) joins, more specifically: with as many left joins as the maximum depth of the tree, it will be possible in one query. This is the reason a lot of people tend to save the 'depth' of a specific category, so you 'll be able to filter and limit the amount of joins to the same table to a more sane amount.

Personally, for regularly altering data: I tend to configure a trigger on an insert / update, which will save / cache the current 'path' of a node based on id's (for instance: a path is '12/62/28/345', in which every step between the delimiter `/` is the primary key of a parent node in the correct order (345's parent is 28, 28's parent is 62, etc.)), so I can query it with just one join like this (/ used as separator):

```
SELECT j.*
FROM tablename o
JOIN tablename j
WHERE j.path LIKE CONCAT (o.path,'/%')
AND  j.id != o.id  -- skip parent asked for.
WHERE o.id = <the id of the node you're looking for>;
```